# Switch a Transistor ON/OFF with Txd Line From USB2SER Adapter (CH340)?[Resolved]

Tags: transistors, rs232

**Note/Update:**
The Problem was The Use of an extension cable (**RS232 Null Modem Without Handshaking**).So, The RxD & TxD are inverted.it means if you want to measure TxD voltage You should Get it from The Pin **2**.

I have an USB2Ser Adapter (CH340), and want to use the TxD line to control an 13V voltage On/Off. (The pins RTS,DTR already occupied.So, really stuck only with TxD).

After some tests i found that the Txd Pin change state between (0V & 0.42V) (logical 1 & logical 0). So, We have Two states 0V & 0.42V.  
 
0V ------> Transistor is OFF. is OK. 
0.42V ---> Transistor is ON. is it possible ??

**UPDATE :**
DataSheet : http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/7/7c/CH340DS1_EN.PDF (from @WhatRoughBeast)
TTL levels of My Adapter are : **0V & 3.5V** 
  RTS, DTR lines : logical 0 = **3.5V** , logical 1 = **0V** . So, are normal. it's OK.
  
To test the TxD line i used a BREAK command to make it at logical_zero (3.5V), but when sending a BREAK (**Pyserial.sendBreak(Time)**) i got a **0.42V** on TxD, and as the guys said is abnormal.
i think that My adapter doesn't support the **BREAK** fucntion.
And When Transmitting 00 on TXD Line I got : **0.2V** not normal ... WTF !!!.

I used AccessPort software http://www.usconverters.com/downloads/tools/AccessPort136.zip  to test the Adapter in loopback mode (TxD to RxD), And Transmitting Some Words, the Test is passed !! what i send, i get it in the Receive window. it means that My Adapter is O.K !!!

Comment: If you can find a germanium transistor (0.2V turn on) - yes.

Comment: Thank you for the help.but do you have any name ?

Comment: If TX is really only going as high as 420 mV, then something else is already wrong.

Comment: Something seems really wrong with your logic HI voltage.  Are you sure that it isn't driving the pin of a micro that is set to output and LO?  Please try disconnecting the TxD pin from whatever it is connected to and measure again.

Comment: Why don't your use Op-Amp? Set the inverting ping to 0.2V using resistor. and it will switch output on 0.2V

Comment: OK, To make TxD in logical_0 (High Voltage) I send a BREAK command (PySerail.SendBreak()), and with a Multimeter i got 0.42V on TXD line, Is that mean that my adapter doesn't Support BREAK fucntion ??

Comment: @DwayneReid I'm just attaching a multimeter to the TxD pin. i disconnected the Txd from the Multimeter & measure it again, it's the same 420 mV.

Comment: Do you want steady state switching or just a short switching?

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar I'll try the idea, thankx

Comment: @Arsenal steady state

Comment: If you are measuring the 0.42 v with a meter, the lead might be pulsing and you are seeing an average.  Do you have a scope so you can observe the waveform?

Comment: @tcrosley Thank you for the idea, i don't have a scope but i think it's the problem, i'll give it a try.thankx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly you are measuring your Tx line wrong. If you take a look at the data sheet http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/7/7c/CH340DS1_EN.PDF Table 6.2 says that you should be seeing ~3 volts. A break command does not normally send a DC level - it sends a logical level for 1 or more character transmit times. So your multimeter is looking at a fairly narrow pulse and averaging it.

As a quick check, try sending a continuous stream of 00 data. This should (assuming 1 start, 1 stop, no parity) give you a DMM reading of ~80% of the actual high voltage.

Comment: When Trasmitting 00 on TXD, I got : 0.2V !! It's abnormal.So, To test My adapter I used AccessPort software with LoopBack mode (Txd to Rxd),and send Some Words, The test is Passed !!! What i send i'll get it on the Receive Window.it means the Adapter function well. Any Suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

I'm Such an idiot Lazy Hobbyist, I didn't mention that I'm Using an "**RS232 extension Cable**"
**Adapter (Male)** ---> **(Female) Null Modem Cable (Female)** ----> **Multimeter** 

And After Some help & tests I figured out that this cable is **RS232 Null Modem without handshaking** cable.
and RxD, TxD are inverted. http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/cable/RS-232.html#null

And As @WhatRoughBeast Said i got : ~3V in the TxD (Pin 2 in the Other Side) line when transmitting 00.
Thank you Very much Guys for The help.